# Como faço para pegar uma imagem do computador dentro de uma aplicação java?

Tags: java, swing

Tenho um cadastro e nesse cadastro gostaria que o usuário pudesse escolher uma imagem para o representar. Caso contrário, uma imagem padrão apareceria.

Ou seja, numa determinada parte do cadastro teria um botão que quando clicado abrisse o gerenciador do Windows para a escolha da imagem, mas que restringisse para que apenas escolhesse uma imagem e algo do "tipo" imagem, sem ser um documento, por exemplo.

Com fica o atributo para representar essa imagem? Como fazer isso de uma forma simples?

Comment: Vê se ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/a/11301085/3792998

Comment: Acredito que tu quer algo assim http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Comment: Obrigado @MaiconCarraro  e jsantos1991 obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve utilizar um [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) com [FileFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileFilter.html). [Nos tutoriais oficiais da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html), há um exemplo de como restringi-lo a arquivos com extensão de imagem, apenas.

Veja esta parte, especificamente: [Filtering the List of Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html#filters).